# Graph SDK: Create authprovider using client assertion in Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to create an authprovider with client assertion, signed JWT, instead of client secret to create an instance of a Microsoft Graph client.

I found an example of creating an authprovider with client secret in following page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=Java

However, I cannot find the article on how to create an authprovider with client assertion.
Would it be possible or not supported yet? If it's possible, please let me know how.